# What are the data protection features available in snowflake cloud data warehouse?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What are the data protection features available in snowflake cloud data warehouse like RAID, Cliques, Hot Standby Nodes, Fallback, Journaling, and Locks. available in teradata.

Comment: The Snowflake documentation answers these questions pretty perfectly - https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Look for below in Snowflake, AWS and Azure docs against each of these terms and/or concepts used in Teradata. There is not an exact 1-1 relationship here as mentioned in other answers, but concepts wise this may be a good starting point, these are loosely related topics across the two.

RAID: Storage on AWS S3 or Azure Blob storage

Cliques: Imagine it is one large clique (its a graph where the maximal clique is the graph itself as I'd say in graph theory - Completely Connected Graph). All nodes will have access to all the disk!

Hot Standby Nodes: Imagine you have no nodes when idle. As soon as your run a query on a virtual warehouse those nodes become active nodes. Alternatively, you may think every node in your warehouse is an HSN, when a query runs they become active. How many nodes? Up to the customer on how much they want (cloud).

Fallback: Read about Time Travel and Fail Safe.

Journaling: No relevant concept here. Time Travel, Fail Safe, Table Streams come to mind but the usecase with journaling is different.

Locks: Partition locks vs row hash locks, table level locks are similar for updates (full table) and merge statements. If you have a Snowflake account, you may run Show locks in account statement in the UI to see active locks in account. Blocking is similar too excpet that you dont have those HUT or Mload type locks in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Snowflake_Security_Overview_WP.pdf) has a detailed description of the security techniques used in Snowflake.

Also for further reading this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj2sf2ez4fmAhVaT30KHTv3DLMQFjAKegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.snowflake.com%2Fdata-warehousing-glossary%2Fdata-protection%2F&usg=AOvVaw3KChAF-t0w3PjY29uCHxwq) would be helpful as it gives a overview of the security needed in data warehousing.

Answer (score 0):

Being in the cloud, Snowflake's data store is distributed, so *similar* to RAID but not exactly.  Snowflake lets you resize the compute resource (called a warehouse) and spin up new nodes easily, so "hot standby".  You can even resize nodes in code.  (I've even done it in SSIS pacckages).

There is a way to view query history.

I have not run into any "locks" functionality.

Fail safe is a Snowflake data restoration service.  You can request a data backup in the event of operation emergencies.

Time travel is a configurable data history function where you can see data as of or before a point in time.  You set the data retention to a value between 0 and 90 days and users can query table data AS OF or BEFORE a timestamp or before a query was run.  You could select data into a restore_table as of a certain point in time and swap the restore_table and the current_table.

Additionally, Snowflake data is encrypted at rest.  You can use their keys or implement your own keys integrated AWS KMS.  Snowflake is PCI DSS and HIPAA compliant.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, when you have an instance of Snowflake environment, under the cover, it is backed by durable and highly resilient Cloud storage provided by Cloud vendors (AWS, Azure, GCP).  Alot of the traditional database (the like of Teradata) hardware setup need not apply to the new platform.

Instead, DBAs are welcomed to reposition their effort to focus on new management tasks (working with compute clusters and scaling, using unique features such as cloning with time travel to do backup with initially zero copy of data, and many).  In terms of transaction and concurrency control (the lock-related question), Snowflake supports read committed snapshot isolation which favors large concurrent reads with some writes.  The locking is done automatically by the system with some details described in documentation here:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/transactions.html#resource-locking and can be summarized:
- Readers (queries) don't lock data, not blocking other transactions from writing (update/delete/merge)
- Writers don't block other transactions from reading data
- Writers block other writers to prevent dirty reads
This isolation level is to support ACID like behavior for high concurrency of OLAP workloads.